# Teradata: MULTISET vs SET Table performance

Tags: teradata, unique-constraint

So **SET** tables involve a performance impact, as for every new row inserted or updated in the table, Teradata checks if a duplicate row already exists in the table, which can be a serious issue if there is a large number of records. However, we can improve its performance by defining a unique constraint on any column in the SET table, such as a Unique Primary Index (**UPI**). This helps us avoid the additional overhead of performing the duplicate row check, as the UPI guarantees that there will be no duplicate rows.

1. Does this mean that a SET table with a UPI/USI will have the **same performance** as a MULTISET table with a UPI/USI? **Please explain**.
2. And if your table has a Unique Primary Index, should you create it as a SET or a MULTISET table?

Answer (score 2):

There will be no performance difference for a SET/MULTISET table with a **UPI**, there's just a difference regarding Insert/Select: a SET table silently ignores duplicate rows (#rows inserted less than #rows selected) while a MULTISET table  throws an error (Duplicate row checks are done before checking for uniqueness).

But adding a **USI** will **not** prevent duplicate row checks, a new row has to be inserted into the base table first to create it's ROWID before it's inserted into the USI subtable.